# Why doesn't While loop start?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have the following code, everything seems to be working except for the `while` loop, here is the code:

```
JLabel img = new JLabel(loadingScreens.getImageIcon(0));
    loadingFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    double width = screenSize.getWidth();
    double height = screenSize.getHeight();
    int wid = (int) width;
    int hgt = (int) height;
    wid = wid/2;
    hgt = hgt/2;
    wid -=350;
    hgt -=350;
    loadingFrame.setLocation(wid, hgt);

    loadingFrame.setSize(700, 700);
    loadingFrame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    loadingFrame.add(img);
    loadingFrame.setIconImage(loadingScreens.getImage(0));
    loadingFrame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("Done 1");
    try{
    Thread.sleep(500);
    System.out.println("Done 2");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("exception caught");
    }

    Integer lo = 0;
    System.out.println("Done 3");
    while(lo.equals(256)){

        System.out.println("Started 4");

        loadingFrame.setBackground(new Color(lo, lo, lo, lo));

        loadingFrame.repaint();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }catch(Exception e2){

        }
        lo++;
    }
```

`loadingFrame` being a basic JFrame.

Any help is useful

Comment: What is `lo.equals(256)` ? `0.equals(256)` ?

Comment: Well, it's pretty obvious. Your `lo` contains the value `0`, and it's not equal to `256`.

Comment: but add the end I have lo++ which should add one

Comment: @user2317720, you are setting that value *inside* the loop -- that very loop you've pointed out never starts.

Comment: It's a "while" loop, not an "until" loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A while loop loops while the specified condition is `true`.  You've initialized `lo` to 0, which is not equal to 256, so the loop body is never entered.

Because you increment `lo` in the loop, perhaps you meant the opposite:

```
while(!lo.equals(256)){
```

The `!` operator in Java negates the boolean condition, so that it reads: "while lo is *not* equal to 256".

Answer (score 1):

This because while always start with a `truth` statement not a `false` and your `lo.equals("256")` is giving `false` because  `lo = 0`  and  zero never ever equals 256.

If you want to start the loop you have to negation the condition like this :

```
while(!lo.equals("256") 
//then start the loop
```